# best among flutter channels?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Flutter version?
-stable
-beta
-others
which is the best one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four channels available

1. stable
2. beta
3. dev
4. master.

If you have not configured anything else you’re most likely on `stable channel`

---

The `stable channel` has new builds roughly once a quarter. This is the only channel that is recommended for **production use** although the only difference compared to the beta channel is that there has been a stabilization period. Apart from that, no further automatic tests were performed.

The `beta channel` contains builds that are at most a month and on average two weeks old. After about a quarter the build is going into the stable channel. The changes since the last beta release can be found here.

The `dev channel` contains the latest master build which has run full tests. There is a continuous transformation from master to dev, which builds this channel at most a week old but mostly about a day. Everyone can report a bad build that contains issues. These issues will appear in this list until they are fixed.

The `master channel` has the most recent build. No tests were run before build so there might be broken functionality when using this channel.

---

> Which one should I use?

It really depends on your use case.

**Case 1** : Developing an app to be released in Production environment - `Use Stable Channel`

**Case 2** : You want to try out new features (But they can still have build issues)  - `Use Beta Channel`

**Case 3 :** Want to contribute to newest issues on github - `use dev channel`

**Case 4 :** Not recommended to use as might contain broken functionalities - `master channel`

> Always prefer stable version unless you want to contribute in open source

Comment: I would also mention that master gets high frequented updates where it could happen everytime that something is breaks. Bleeding edge so to say. Its really nothing where you should do any serious project.

Comment: @ChrisPi absolutely! Master branches are for those who are truly following flutter development for a long and can understand the real-time changes happening. Such branches are not for developing projects but rather for developing flutter's next stable version

Comment: @anirudh thanks alot for above info :). Can u please tell me which sql tech to go with ?? :)

Comment: @Samama Hi, do you mean sql tech for flutter? Could you please elaborate or post another question?

Comment: @Samama if you liked my answer please mark it as correct. This would help another developers in future :)

Comment: @anirudh Hi! Yes SQL for flutter? SQL lite, PSQL which one among all available one for saving data for dev of food ordering etc like apps??